# QCA Report “Failed to load Legacy provider”

Tags: c++, qt, openssl, qgis, qcar-sdk

windows 10 install：

vs2019

Win64OpenSSL-3_0_5

qca-2.3.4

qt-5.15.2

using cmake build and install to qt directory

then I test the library.

```
bool temp = QCA::isSupported("cert", QStringLiteral("qca-ossl"));
```

the program exit here,and report “Failed to load Legacy provider”

note，this code used by qgis.

the program load dll correctly！

```
QCA::Initializer init;

QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

QCA::scanForPlugins();

bool temp4s = QCA::isSupported("sha224", QStringLiteral("qca-ossl"));
```

Comment: Did you add `target_link_libraries( ${QCA_LIBRARY} ${QCA_INCLUDE_DIR})` to your `CMakeLists.txt` file ?

Comment: Please clarify the question and provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it.